# Responsive design of the question list isn't compact enough on small screens

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design, responsive-design

If I understand correctly, the current mobile version of the site is obsolete and is no longer updated, the official mobile app is officially dead, and the full version of the site with adaptive design is to be used instead.

My biggest problem with the responsive design is the massive difference in how much information fits on the screen, compared to the old mobile design. This is most noticable in long lists without big paragraphs of text.

[image: Comparison between full and mobile versions of the questions list]

Not only titles use a font a bit larger than necessary, but there's a lot of wasted empty space. A whole line is dedicated to votes, answers and views, where old mobile version packs all information on the side.

This is important on small screens of mobile phones. Old mobile version can fit almost twice the number of questions on the screen.

Furthermore, I'd question the wording of "−3 votes" and "0 votes", especially considering the numbers displayed are scores, not number of votes.

Comment: I feel like there was missed opportunity when the responsive/theme changes were deployed to put the **Ask Question** button on the right side of the header (where the logo is on each site). The "top questions" title could have been on the same line as the filter buttons and that would have saved a bunch of space. Plus the right side of the header is pretty much unused space.

Comment: @KodosJohnson This feels like a desktop-first design. I doesn't look like anybody has put any thought into the mobile design, it's just a desktop design with random CSS tweaks to avoid scrollbars on a small screen.