# Can we have some details about when the responsive site will become the default on mobile?

Tags: discussion, design, mobile-web, responsive-design

The responsive "full site" will [replace the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/270345) sooner or later.

- Is there a timeline on when it might become the default?
- Will this be done piecemeal, or as a whole (for a given SE site, or for all SE sites)?
- Will the mobile site (or parts thereof) be retained for a while after the responsive site becomes the default, or removed immediately? (We know it will [be removed completely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/270345) - but will that be in one go when the responsive design becomes the default, or as and when parts are ported to responsive design, or some time after that?)

Comment: Profile page is still not responsive at all and looks very bad on mobile. Same for review. Those are major parts of the site, so guess they wait until they're responsive.

Comment: The most serious problem with the responsive site in day-to-day operation is that it [massively wastes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343387) the little space there is on mobile devices: almost twice as many questions fit on the screen in the original mobile site.

Comment: Then there are also problems with [bandwidth usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343182).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek yes, that's what prompted this question. In particular, the line "we have begun (and continue) to remove the mobile views, in favor of using one view for all browsers, featuring a responsive web design" from Yaakov Ellis's♦ answer.