# Why is the mobile web so limited?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

The mobile web is very limited and is lacking lots of features that are available in the desktop (full site) version. Why is that? What is the reasoning?

Some example of the things I can't do on mobile web theme:

1. I can't watch the number of votes for and against
2. To create a description before it you need to flip through by hand, you can't enter its name in the search
   [image]
3. It's inconvenient to check edits. You need to go to the tags, participants or ask a question. Only after it does the edit button appear
4. I can't really look at the result of the edit or response. Available only during question assignment
5. Can't run the code from a snippet
6. Can't edit the profile
7. I can't change the tracking label

Comment: Mobile view is called mobile view because it has limited some of the functions of the full site. You might want to wait for the responsive project to be complete as it will bring the full site to smaller form factors as well.

Comment: At least few of these can be done by using the desktop mode in your phone.

Comment: my question is not a duplicate. so says how to get all the functionality, and I want to know why it's missing from the mobile version

Comment: Well, I guess the answer to "*why it's missing from the mobile version*" is because the development has moved from mobile view to responsive web (which should cater both desktop and mobile in the future), or in other words: mobile view is being deprecated slowly.

Comment: The only reason why the mobile site still exists is so a minimal view is available for users with very slow connections (e.g. dial-up). A lot of the functionality is stripped to save data usage and allow faster loads.

Comment: Agree it's not a duplicate. It's not asking "How", but rather "Why". Reopened.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog The full site is unusable on mobile devices because it massively wastes screen space, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343387/responsive-design-of-the-question-list-isnt-compact-enough-on-small-screens . This has nothing to do with slow connections.